# Java How to read text file line by line and get that line's text separately (length text)

Tags: java

I have text file like this.

```
12A   aa65 3244 5          665     fr    65  3434344344343     888dds     77786334 6h
1114  22   6FF  7    d     M6      h     o8  665466676         8Pt        543NNv   9
```

The file is in columns of varying widths, e.g., the first column is 6 characters wide, the second column is 5, the third is 5, and so on.

I want to split each line into the values in the columns, like this for the first line:

```
12A , aa65 , 3244 , 5 , , 665 , fr , 65 , 3434344344343 , 888dds , 77786334 , 6h
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. What are the criteria for how you split up the lines?

Comment: Currently your question is quite vague to be answered. What do you mean by 6 length and 5 length. Can you describe the criteria a little more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a Scanner to read the file and the subString(start, end) method to parse each field.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myFile"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   String aLine = sc.nextLine();
   String field1 = aLine.subString(0,6);
   String field2 = aLine.subString(6,11);
   ...
}
```

Comment: yes, u r correct. i found my food :D thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer**:

Ah, okay, you want to split up the text by the width of the columns. It looks like your column lengths are:

```
6
5
5
6
8
6
4
18
9
(the rest)
```

So read the lines with [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and then just use [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to get the individual parts of them, and possibly [`String#trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to trim off whitespace:

```
BufferedReader r = /*...get a BufferedReader for your input...*/;
String line;
String[] parts;
int[] columns = new int[]{ // The starting index of each column
    6,
    5+6,
    5+5+6,
    6+5+5+6,
    8+6+5+5+6,
    6+8+6+5+5+6,
    4+6+8+6+5+5+6,
    18+4+6+8+6+5+5+6,
    9+18+4+6+8+6+5+5+6
};
int i;
int start, end;
int linelen;

// Read each line
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    // Get its length
    linelen = line.length();

    // Get an array for the result
    parts = new string[columns.length];

    // Loop through our column starting indexes
    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i ) {
        // Get the start and end indexes for this column
        start = columns[i];
        end = i < columns.length - 1 ? columns[i+1] : linelen;

        // Is the string long enough?
        if (linelen < start) {
            // No, use null
            parts[i] = null;
        }
        else {
            // Yes, grab the text
            parts[i] = line.substring(start, end > linelen ? linelen : end);

            // Note - you may want `.trim()` on the end of the above, if you
            // don't want trailing spaces (or leading spaces, but none of your
            // examples has leading spaces).
        }
    }

    // **Use the `parts` of this line.
}
```

You might also consider using a class rather than an array for `parts`, and putting the parsing logic for it within the class.

---

**Original answer**:

It *sounds* like you're looking for a combination of [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
BufferedReader r = /*...get a BufferedReader for your input...*/;
String line;
String[] parts;

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    parts = line.split(" +");
    // Use the `parts` array
}
```

`readLine` reads lines from the input.

`split` splits a string into a string array using a delimiter defined by a regular expression. In your case, it looks like the delimiter is just one or more spaces.

Comment: yes. it's read line. but i want to get text of that line by length

Comment: Since split takes a regex, and he has variable spaces, couldn't he split with (" +")?

Comment: @LakmalUdayanga: What does "by length" mean?

Comment: @Kon: Thanks, for some reason I was thinking `split` would combine empty segments, but of course it won't.

Comment: No prob. Doing so will give OP his array and he can concatenate it however he wants.

Comment: @ T.J , i cant use    spilt(" ")

Ex : 11   87098           766
     234  67              hu
     ww5g 657             454534534535545

11 , 234 , ww5g is 1 column. but 11 , 234 , ww5g length is change. if i use length 5 . i can get all text

Comment: @LakmalUdayanga: Until or unless you tell us what you mean when you say "by length," it's impossible to help you. Similarly, saying "I can't use X" is pointless. You have to say ***why***.

Comment: @ TJ , every word have length.ex : this word Apple(length is 6). i want to get text by length

Comment: @T.J , i found answer see "quartzde" answer. i mean that thing. please see and tell me about that. thak you

Comment: @LakmalUdayanga: I see now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readline()` and then `split` by space.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do a string split like [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm).

i assume you have read the file and just want to split it.

use `Str.split("\n")` for lines and `Str.split(" ")` for spaces ( if needed)

Answer (score 1):

Several forms of reader in java have a .ReadLine() method.
This will read input from the source until a newline character is encountered.

for file reading I usually use BufferedReader as a wrapper around a FileReader, as this is more efficient for bulk reading. (FileReaders read from the file for every call to a read method.)

edit to add:
if you want the results sorted, it's going to be *much* more efficient to read the data fully into memory then sort, since random disk access is very slow.

reading lines into a list or priority queue, with a custom comparator would achieve what you're after.